# File creation permissions error in fortran

Tags: apache, fortran

I am running a hysplit model and it gets hung up on a particular line of code that came with the hysplit package. It is meant to create a file and open it. It is a .F file and the code is as follows

```
831 OPEN(KF21,FILE=TRIM(MESSG)//'.'//'20150715')
```

with previous lines

```
650 MESSG='MESSAGE'
```

and I am getting the error

```
Fortran runtime error: Permission denied trying to open file 'MESSAGE.20150715'
```

Is there something wrong with the syntax or is this a systems issue? I have checked and to the best of my knowledge the .F file has all of the correct permissions. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am on an apache system if that makes a difference.

Comment: The "permission denied" will be referring to the output file/directory rather than the `.F` file itself.

Comment: What is the content of FNAME, also seen the specified length of 20150715

Comment: @francescalus this has to be the problem but as I was not the one who wrote these programs I am having trouble finding which directory it is trying to create the file in. Is there any quick/easy way of finding this?

Comment: Very likely to be the working directory of the running executable.

Comment: @ThomasBritton, the question of albert is capital. Also, I am curious about the TRIME function that you are using? Is that a function defined in your code? or it is typo in calling the funtion TRIM? I insist on those because, it is not possible to get help if what you show is already wrong.

Comment: @innoSPG it was a typo when I was typing the question, I also changed the actual program for now for troubleshooting purposes. Everything is edited to show everything correctly